# resize a window to mobile size in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

guys i am beginner in bootstrap and i have that code

```html
<head>
  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head> 

<div class="container-fluid">
  
  <div class="page-header">
   <h1>First Bootstrap Project</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2" id="menus">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
     <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>


 </div>
```

and what i want is when re-sizing the window to mobile size the menus should dissappear  ??? i tried a lot but never reached

Comment: Have you written any `script` to make that happen ?

Comment: i tried $(window).resize but i didint work out .. any suggestions ??

Comment: I suggest you to read the [Getting Started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) section for Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the navbar section on this link, http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar. The code example they provide hides the menu when the screen is adjusted to phone size.

Answer (score 0):

display as a button on mobile view.....

```
 <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
```

or use this [bare template](http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-bare) for leanring

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,

```
function AdjustLayoutonResize() {
        windowWidth = $(window).width();
        windowHeight = $(window).height();
        fixedwidth = screenwidth;

     if (windowWidth <= fixedwidth) {
              $('#menus').css({ 'width': sliderwidth, 'display': none});
                }
                else {
                $('#menus').css({ 'width': sliderwidth, 'display': 'block' });
               }
             }
```